# Where is Smoke in 2.83.10?

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I am trying to create something that requires the *Physics > Smoke* and it's not shown on my physics panel. The version I'm using is 2.83.10 and I have included a screen shot of my physics panel and on from a YouTube tutorial screen shot using the same version [[image: my physics tab no Smoke available1] a tutorial physics tab [image: shows Smoke in physics tab].

In the Blender documentation online it shows the panel has a Smoke setting for creating a Smoke Domain. Did it move to another location? Or is it in an Add-On in the preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smoke and fluid simulations changed with the introduction of [mantaflow](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/Physics)

The settings are in ***Fluid***.

- To create the smoke emitter, or [*Flow*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/flow.html).

  Set the *Type* to ***Flow***

  And the *Flow Type* to ***Smoke***.

  [image]
- For the [*Domain*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/domain/settings.html?highlight=smoke)

  Set the *Type* to ***Domain***

  And the *Domain Type* to ***Gas***

  [image]

For a simpler way to set flow and domain simultaneously, just select the object, press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type **quick smoke**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply and also thanks for the f3 shortcut as well.